# How to split a string in bash script

Tags: string, bash

Trying to extract some parts of a string into variables. Initial string looks like this: `/dev/sdc2: LABEL="PAKAGE" UUID="9501DCBF768CEBB9" TYPE="ntfs"`
I getting correct `PORT` and `LABE`L values, but cant get the rest: `UUID` and `TYPE`. Instead of them I getting just a piece of it.

```
#!/bin/bash

INDEX1=""
INDEX2=""
LENGTH=""
PORT=""
LABEL=""
UUID=""
TYPE=""

line=`echo /dev/sdc2: LABEL="PAKAGE" UUID="9501DCBF768CEBB9" TYPE="ntfs" | sed s/\"//g`
echo $line

INDEX1=`expr index "$line" /dev/`
PORT=${line:$INDEX1-1:9}

INDEX1=`expr index "$line" LABEL=`
INDEX2=`expr index "$line" UUID`
INDEX1=`expr $INDEX1 + 5`
INDEX2=`expr $INDEX2 - 2`
LABEL=${line:$INDEX1:$INDEX2-$INDEX1}

INDEX1=`expr index "$line" UUID=`
INDEX2=`expr index "$line" TYPE`
INDEX1=`expr $INDEX1 + 4`
INDEX2=`expr $INDEX2 - 2`
UUID=${line:$INDEX1:$INDEX2-$INDEX1}

INDEX1=`expr index "$line" TYPE=`
INDEX1=`expr $INDEX1 + 4`
TYPE=${line:$INDEX1}

echo $PORT
echo $LABEL
echo $UUID
echo $TYPE


Here the output of this script:
/dev/sdc2: LABEL=PAKAGE UUID=9501DCBF768CEBB9 TYPE=ntfs
/dev/sdc2
PAKAGE
GE UUID=9501DCBF768CEBB9 T
KAGE UUID=9501DCBF768CEBB9 TYPE=ntfs
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: It would be better/safer to not do this in bash at all: The Python `shlex` module (in the standard library) is a better lexer for shell syntax than anything bash has available built-in. Otherwise, you end up with approaches that either are dangerous (as with `eval`) or fragile (as with trying to roll your own parser).

Comment: I do not know python unfortunately (as well as regexp)

Answer (score 3):

I think it's better done with regexp.

```
#!/bin/bash
src='/dev/sdc2: LABEL="PAKAGE" UUID="9501DCBF768CEBB9" TYPE="ntfs"'

regex='([^:]+): LABEL="([^"]+)" UUID="([^"]+)" TYPE="([^"]+)"'

if [[ $src =~ $regex ]]; then
    echo "matches"
    i=1
    n=${#BASH_REMATCH[*]}
    while [[ $i -lt $n ]]
    do
        echo "  capture[$i]: ${BASH_REMATCH[$i]}"
        let i++
    done
else
    echo "does not match"
fi
```

Output:

```
 matches
  capture[1]: /dev/sdc2
  capture[2]: PAKAGE
  capture[3]: 9501DCBF768CEBB9
  capture[4]: ntfs
```

Based on [this](http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-regular-expressions).

Comment: A more generic regex would be `regex='([^:]+): LABEL="([^"]+)" UUID="([^"]+)" TYPE="([^"]+)"'` -- that does not assume anything about the values of the variables

Comment: I do not think its possible with regexp due to different delimiters. But it really works just fine. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This uses `eval` and is therefore risky. Ensure you know where your data is coming from.

```
$ line='/dev/sdc2: LABEL="this is the label" UUID="this is the uuid" TYPE="ntfs"'
$ IFS=: read port variables <<< "$line"
$ echo "$port"
/dev/sdc2
$ echo "$variables"
 LABEL="this is the label" UUID="this is the uuid" TYPE="ntfs"
$ eval "$variables"
$ printf "%s='%s'\n" label "$LABEL" uuid "$UUID" type "$TYPE"
label='this is the label'
uuid='this is the uuid'
type='ntfs'
```

Answer (score 1):

Defining patterns over values, instead of keys, isn't the best way to deal with parsing. You might be better off doing it this way:

```
$ line='/dev/sdc2: LABEL="PAKAGE" UUID="9501DCBF768CEBB9" TYPE="ntfs"'
$ entry=( ${line//\"/} )

$ PORT=${entry[0]} PORT=${PORT//:/}     # defining variable PORT
$ declare ${entry[1]}                   # defining variable LABEL
$ declare ${entry[2]}                   # defining variable UUID
$ declare ${entry[3]}                   # defining variable TYPE    

$ echo -e "${PORT}\n${LABEL}\n${UUID}\n${TYPE}"
sdc2:
PAKAGE
9501DCBF768CEBB9
ntfs
```

Comment: @1_CR Mis-reverse-engineered the OP's example (: Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: You're assuming there's no whitespace in the quoted values.

Answer (score 0):

You could resort to simply clearing the string of all the undesirable portions and using `read` to populate your variables

```
read -r PORT LABEL UUID TYPE <<< "$(echo '/dev/sdc2: LABEL="PAKAGE" UUID="9501DCBF768CEBB9" TYPE="ntfs"' |\
sed 's/\(.*\): \+LABEL="\([^"]\+\)" \+UUID="\([^"]\+\)" \+TYPE="\([^"]\+\)"/\1 \2 \3 \4/')"
echo $PORT
/dev/sdc2
echo $LABEL
PAKAGE
echo $UUID
9501DCBF768CEBB9
echo $TYPE
ntfs
```

Comment: You are assuming there is no whitespace in any of the variable values.

Comment: @glennjackman, you're right. I actually like your `eval` solution better

Answer (score 0):

Without `eval`, but same logic using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) :

```
$ line=\"/dev/sdc2: LABEL="PAKAGE" UUID="9501DCBF768CEBB9" TYPE="ntfs"\"
$ echo "${line%% *}"
/dev/sdc2
$ echo "$LABEL"
PAKAGE
$ echo "$UUID"
9501DCBF768CEBB9
$ echo "$TYPE"
ntfs
```

Comment: I don't get that output: I see `"/dev/sdc2:` and `ntfs"`

Comment: Added `bash` requirement.